# is it possible to remove the "+" and "-" after a diff comparison

Tags: diff

So If I do a diff comparison the file that is createt has the "+" or "-" sign at the beginning of every line. Is there a possibility of removing those, or use another comparison tool to do it without the "+" or "-"?

so I think that its maybe possible to change the parameters of the diff comment.

```
a.txt content:
Dog
Cat
Ape
---------------------
b.txt content:
Dog
Cat
```

```
diff a.txt b.txt > c.txt
```

```
output:
-Ape
```

Comment: Why do you want this? How else will you know what kind of differences are output? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can't you just use `grep` to identify the lines you want to keep (which are what? removals only?) and `sed` to remove the symbols you don't?

Comment: For the context, I have 2 databases witch are in 2 diffrent locations, Germany and China, One is a master, and the otherone the slave, I dont have acces to the servers where the database is locatet because the server is locatet at a service provider. I want to compare two .sql files and write out the differences in a 3rd one witch Ill then upload to the Chinese Database so that one is up to date every few hours. Becuase of that Im not able to have the "+" and "-" signs in the sql file since becuase  of them I cant upload the file the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pipe the output of `diff` into `grep` to filter to only the lines you want to keep - which appear to be removals only - followed by `sed` to remove the symbols you don't want.

```
git diff a.txt b.txt | grep '^-' | sed 's/^-//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `LFMT` option, `--LFMT-line-format=LFMT` where you replace the `--LFMT` with `--old`, `--new`, or `--unchanged`:

- `--old` -> lines found in the left file (or old file), but not the right (or new file)
- `--new` -> lines found in the right file, but not the left
- `--unchanged` -> lines common to both files

The `%L` allows us to retrieve the line and keep (end it with) a newline , use `%l` if you want to remove the trailing newlines.

The options to remove newlines in `diff` (`-B`,`-b`, `-w`, etc.) seem to be be disabled, without error, when trying to customize the output format.

To get around this, need to massage some data with an inverted `grep` or maybe a `sed` command (`sed  '/^$/d'`) to remove the blank lines. I like sorting and ditching the blanks this way as it's clean and keeps your database clean.

```
diff <(sort a.txt | grep -v '^$' ) <(sort b.txt | grep -v '^$') --old-line-format='%L' --new-line-format='%L' --unchanged-line-format=''
```

```
$ diff a.txt b.txt
3c3
< Ape
---
>
$ echo -e "\n\nFish" >> b.txt
$ diff a.txt b.txt
3c3
< Ape
---
> Fish
$ diff <(sort a.txt | grep -v '^$' ) <(sort b.txt | grep -v '^$') \ 
--old-line-format='%L' --new-line-format='%L' --unchanged-line-format=''
Ape
Fish
$
```